# Weird review audit

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I stumbled upon this answer as an audit today:

[image]

How is simply "No.", even if correct, a high quality answer, without elaborating on it?

Yes I have read the comments on the answer, and I see a point in "there isn't anything further to say", but I'd still say it's a very poor choice to audit on, one would expect more on basically any topic, imho.